# Reflexive and Irreflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I've seen an example that goes as follows:

Let $R$ be an irreflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive relation on a set $A$.

$A = \{1,2,3\}$

$R = \{(1,1)(1,2),(2,3)(1,3)\} $

How can the relation $R$ include $(1,1)$? Wouldn't that just make it neither reflexive or irreflexive.

I thought for relations to hold they were required to hold for **all $x \in A$.** Therefore it isn't irreflexive anymore because the condition **$(x,x) \notin R$** is broken by $(1,1)$.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: These damn college textbooks.... LOL, thank you.

Comment: Usually, *irreflexive* means exactly that “for all $x\in A$, $(x,x)\notin R$”, so that relation is not irreflexive. By the way, “irreflexive and transitive” implies “antisymmetric”: if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$, then $(x,x)\in R$ by transitivity, contradicting irreflexivity.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, you are correct. For $R$ a relation on $A$ to be irreflexive, we would require that $\forall a \in A$, $(a,a) \not \in A$. However, that is broken by $a=1$, so $R$ as given is not irreflexive.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*